# Implementing linked list from scratch - Follow up

Tags: python, beginner, linked-list

A follow up for this question:
[Implementing Linked lists in Python from scratch](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224355/implementing-linked-lists-in-python-from-scratch)

Node:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.next = None
```

Linked list:

```
from node import Node


class LinkedList:
    link_connection = ' -> '

    ''' init, getters, setters '''
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.head = Node(key)
        self.tail = self.head
        self.length = 1

    @property
    def head(self):
        return self.__head

    @head.setter
    def head(self, node):
        if node is not None:
            self.__head = node

    @property
    def tail(self):
        return self.__tail

    @tail.setter
    def tail(self, node):
        if node is not None:
            try:
                if node.next is None:
                    self.__tail.next = node
                    self.__tail = self.__tail.next
            except AttributeError:
                self.__tail = node

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.__length

    @length.setter
    def length(self, value):
        self.__length = value

    ''' generator for nodes '''
    ''' iterating, search etc. '''
    def node_generator(self, target=None):
        node = self.head
        yield node
        while node.next is not None and node.next.key != target:
            node = node.next
            yield node

    def __iter__(self):
        return map(lambda node: node.key, self.node_generator())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.link_connection.join(str(key) for key in self)

    def go_forward(self, steps):
        for node in self.node_generator():
            if steps == 0:
                return node
            steps -= 1

    def delete(self, target):
        for node in self.node_generator(target):
            pass
        node.next = node.next.next
        self.length -= 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self.__length

    def append(self, key):
        node = Node(key)
        self.tail = node
        self.length += 1

    def find(self, value):
        for node in self:
            if node == value:
                return node
```

Is this new implementation better?

Answer (score 4):

### Specification and Unit Tests

- You are lacking a clear specification for your methods. We have to guess what these methods do exactly, specially for edge cases.
- You should provide unit tests when providing an API class. You would have found some bugs if you did.

### Review

> ```
>  @head.setter
>     def head(self, node):
>         if node is not None:
>             self.__head = node
> ```

There is no link from the new head to the previous one. Also, what would you do if node.next is already filled?

```
 @head.setter
    def head(self, node):
        if node is not None:
            node.next = self.__head
            self.__head = node
```

---

> ```
> @tail.setter
>     def tail(self, node):
>         if node is not None:
>             try:
>                 if node.next is None:
>                     self.__tail.next = node
>                     self.__tail = self.__tail.next
>             except AttributeError:
>                 self.__tail = node
> ```

Why would you expect an `AttributeError` here? You are only setting `next`. And why would you ignore a tail that has a next node? Why not include the tail chain?

---

> ```
> ''' generator for nodes '''
> ''' iterating, search etc. '''
> def node_generator(self, target=None):
>     node = self.head
>     yield node
>     while node.next is not None and node.next.key != target:
>         node = node.next
>         yield node
> ```

The spec is unclear here. You always include the head, and then continue as long as a next node's `key` does not match the specified `target`. Why not check head for the same condition?

---

> ```
> def delete(self, target):
>     for node in self.node_generator(target):
>         pass
>     node.next = node.next.next
>     self.length -= 1
> ```

What if the node you want to delete is the tail? This edge case is not foreseen.

Comment: about the generator, it's because I want to return the node before the target, any suggestion to do that better?

Comment: If the head is the target, should you yield only the head, or no results?

Comment: OH! I see.
Actually, I don't know what I want to return lol